# Maximal Ideals in the Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

We know that the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ are all ideals of the form $(p)$, where $p$ is prime.  But what if we consider $(p, p_2)$, where $p_2$ is prime, although I'm not sure that the stipulation of $p_2$ being prime is necessary.

$(p,p_2)$ certainly contains $(p)$ because $p$ is in $(p,p_2)$, so $(p)$ is contained in $(p,p_2)$.

Therefore, is it not true that $(p)$ is maximal?

Comment: The ideal $(p,p_2)$ is generated by $\gcd(p,p_2)=1$.

Comment: So, in particular, if you do stipulate that $p_2$ is prime (and different from $p$), then $(p,p_2)=\mathbb{Z}$ is not proper, therefore not maximal.

Comment: i can't seem to find a prop/theorem of that in my book, although i do recognize hearing that in class...do you have a link to the proof?

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow Since you *know* that $(p)$ is maximal, the fact that $p_2\in(p,p_2)$ and $p_2\notin (p)$ (assuming $p_2\ne p$), immediately gives the answer: $(p,p_2)=\dots$.

Comment: One direction, that $(a,b)\subseteq(\gcd(a,b))$, is fairly clear. The other is a consequence of Bézout's identity, which follows from Euclidean algorithm. Wikipedia sketches a proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity

Comment: If an ideal $(a_1,...,a_n)$ is a principal ideal, then it is generated by $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$ (In a more general ring which is not a PID, we only have $(\gcd(a_1,..,a_n))\supseteq(a_1,...,a_n)$). But all ideals in $\Bbb Z$ are principal, since $\Bbb Z$ is a Euclidean ring.

Comment: great, thanks, @MattPressland, clears up a lot of confusion!

Comment: would the corollary, that the finitely generated ideal of two relatively prime elements (of a ring with a multiplicative identity 1) is the entire ring, for any relatively prime integers, be true?  My intuition tells me that it's true, as gcd(a,b)=1 and (a,b) (the ideal generated by a and b) = (gcd(a,b))=(1)=R.

Comment: This is not true for arbitrary rings - you need your ring to be a principal ideal domain. (What you have stated is essentially the defining property of a PID.)

Answer (score 2):

In any principal ideal domain, for the generated ideals we have
$$(a,b)=(\gcd(a,b))\,.$$
So, unless $p_2$ is a power of $p_1$, we will have $(p_1,p_2)=(1)=\Bbb Z$, is not maximal.

Answer (score 1):

I shall attempt to collate some of the comments into an answer.

Let $p$ be prime, and let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $p$ divides $n$, then $(p,n)=(p)$, as $n\in(p)$, so we have no contradiction to maximality of $(p)$.

If $p$ does not divide $n$, then $p$ and $n$ are coprime, and so $(p,n)=(1)=\mathbb{Z}$ as follows. By the Euclidean algorithm (in particular, Bézout's identity), there exist $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\lambda p+\mu n=1$. Therefore $1\in(p,n)$, and $(p,n)=\mathbb{Z}$.

In general, the same identity can be used to prove that $(a,b)=(\gcd(a,b))$; this is the proof that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain.